# if i choose one label then i want to make the other 3 labels un-clickable

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

i have four labels t2,t3,t4 and t5... i want to disable 3 of them if i click on the remaining label

[image]

for example if i choose the option 'B' (India) then i want to make the other 3 labels(options) un-clickable

i have tried

```
t2.setEnabled(false)
t3.setEnabled(false)
t5.setEnabled(false)
```

but this is not working.

Comment: can you provide a bit more code, may be the method where you have written the logic to do this ?

Comment: What libraries are you using for the UI? Best bet is to check the documentation of it.

Comment: private void t4MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                
        t2.setEnabled(false);
        t3.setEnabled(false);
        t5.setEnabled(false);
}

Comment: The code you provided isn't enough to see your problem, you can [edit] your own post to add more information to it. I have an idea on how to solve this but I'm on phone atm so I'll write an answer by tomorrow, try to add a [mcve] for better help sooner :) BTW why are you using `JLabel` instead of `JButton` to get the click event over them?

Comment: you need to have radio buttons and add action listener on each radio button to disable the remaining three.